# Unable to launch Chrome in incognito mode using Selenium WebDriver using C#

Tags: c#, .net, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to launch Chrome using Selenium WebDriver in incognito mode, but not able to accomplish. I tried all options but not able to launch. Below is my code snippet

```
case "chrome":
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.AddArgument("--incognito"); //Line XYZ
    desiredCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Chrome();
    desiredCapabilities.SetCapability(ChromeOptions.Capability, options);
break;

var capabilities = BuildDesiredCapabilities();
webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri(gridHubURL), capabilities,
TimeSpan.FromSeconds(ApplicationConfiguration.RemoteDriverTimeOutValue));
```

Can anyone please help me what I am doing wrong here? I also tried the below code options in Line XYZ

Any pointers will be much helpful.

EDIT1
Please find the updated code here.

```
 public IWebDriver CreateDriver()
    {
        var capabilities = BuildDesiredCapabilities();
        webDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri(gridHubURL), capabilities,
                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(ApplicationConfiguration.RemoteDriverTimeOutValue));            
        webDriver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
        webDriver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(ApplicationConfiguration.TimeOutValue));
        webDriver.Manage().Timeouts().SetPageLoadTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(ApplicationConfiguration.TimeOutValue));
        return webDriver;
    }

    private DesiredCapabilities BuildDesiredCapabilities()
    {
        DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities;
        switch (browserName.ToLower())
        {
            case "firefox":
                desiredCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Firefox();
                break;
            case "chrome":
                desiredCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Chrome();
                desiredCapabilities.SetCapability("chrome.switches", "--incognito");
                break;
            case "ie":
                desiredCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.InternetExplorer();
                desiredCapabilities.SetCapability("ie.ensureCleanSession", true);
                break;
            default:
                desiredCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Firefox();
                break;
        }
        return desiredCapabilities;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The .NET bindings have introduced browser-specific `Options` classes to avoid having to know or understand arbitrary capability values. You were using just such a class, `ChromeOptions`, in your original code. You missed one extra step, though, in how to use the `ChromeOptions` class with `RemoteWebDriver`. The missing piece is that you should use the `ToCapabilities()` method to convert the `ChromeOptions` object to the `ICapabilities` object that `RemoteWebDriver` expects. Your code would look something like the following:

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddArgument("incognito");
var capabilities = options.ToCapabilities();
var driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URI(gridHubURL), capabilities);
```

Comment: Thank you Jim. This is the solution I was looking after.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass parameters to the executable like this:

```
desiredCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Chrome();
desiredCapabilities.SetCapability("chrome.switches", "--incognito");
```

So passing the parameter `--incognito` to the `chrome.switches` capability should work.

**NOTE:**

The `chrome.switches` capability has been deprecated for over two years. A list of the current supported capabilities can be found at the official [chromedriver Google Sites page](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities). Additionally, use of arbitrary capabilities has been discouraged by the Selenium project for some time, particularly when using the .NET bindings

Comment: I am looking for a c# code. I am not sure whether the above one will work

Comment: desiredCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Chrome();
                    desiredCapabilities.SetCapability("chrome.switches", "--incognito");

Comment: I've updated my answer. I didn't realise you were using C#.

Comment: I did that. Chrome opens in normal mode and not in incognito mode. pasting the entire code in my EDIT

Comment: Thanks for your response

Comment: It helped a lot. Accepting it.

Comment: Downvoting this answer as it uses deprecated techniques. The `chrome.switches` capability has been deprecated for over two years. A list of the current supported capabilities can be found at the official [chromedriver Google Sites page](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities). Additionally, use of arbitrary capabilities has been discouraged by the Selenium project for some time, particularly when using the .NET bindings.